# nullable fields in swagger on node.js

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-editor

I've spent a bunch of time trying to find a solution for creating swagger docs in Node.JS. The main library is swagger-node, in which you create a swagger yaml file and then add your controllers to it. It automatically provides swagger ui docs in your app and does validation on the request & response against the models you specify in your yaml.

This is neat, however I have a requirement that some fields I want to explicitly be able to return or accept `null` as a value, for instance:

```
{ 
  id: 123,
  description: "string",
  date_sent: null
}
```

I don't want to delete the `date_sent` key, I want to explicitly state it as null.

The swagger spec does not support `anyOf` which is how JSON schema normally does this I believe.

I'm wondering if there's a workaround? Perhaps some library available for node that has a `x-nullable` vendor specific flag you can add, or some way of specifying that my not-required fields should all be nullable.

Am I going to have to write something myself that takes my swagger file and then modifies it before the validator middleware runs, or is there some workaround someone can suggest?

Comment: Related: [How to define a property that can be string or null in OpenAPI (Swagger)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48111459/113116), [How to specify a property can be null or a reference with Swagger?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40920441/113116)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

SwaggerUI doesn't support nullable types (please, see [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/1920)). But I used nullable properties as:

```
type: ['string','null']
```

After that this property disappears from UI, but validation still worked.

Comment: aha! I tried this, but in yaml I did `string` and `null`

but you have to have quotes around the `'null'` for it to work. Thanks!

Also, if you add a 'default' then it will show up again in the example values, I guess it just doesnt know which one to use as an example

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much! I didn't think about default value. I will try it for my project

Comment: That's not a valid Swagger type definition, by the way.

Comment: As Ron said, this is not valid in OpenAPI/Swagger. [Nazar Gargol's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42797352/113116) is the correct one. See also [How to define a property that can be string or null in OpenAPI (Swagger)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48111459/113116).

Comment: FYI this will make properties with this type not appear in the output of `swagger-codegen` which is one of the most useful tools for Swagger specifications.

Answer (score 22):

`nullable` field is supported in OpenAPI (fka Swagger) Specification [v3.0.0](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.0.md#user-content-schemaNullable), but not in v2.0. Nullable types are defined as follows:

```yaml
# Can be string or null
type: string
nullable: true
```

Comment: Instead of the actual value, I now get `"fieldName": {"present":true}` when I retrieve the data. How do I get the value back into the output?

Comment: --> posted a solution for this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59047331/2750563

Answer (score 5):

Instead of add null in type property, you can use default property instead.

Swagger.json property definition example:

```
"due_date": {
  "type": "string",
  "description": "Due date",
  "default": "null"
},
```

It's a valid Swagger type definition, and still appears as expected in Swagger UI.

Comment: Genius answer for Swagger 2 - no idea why this has not been upvoted - many thanks

Comment: On further research, whilst this seems to work fine, sadly it gives an error in the swagger editor

Comment: This definition is only valid because it uses the string `"null"`, not the actual `null`. This is not what the OP wants.

Comment: Btw, `default: null` (using the actual `null` not the string `"null"`) is not valid in OpenAPI 2.0. The Specification [says](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#schema-object) the `default` value "MUST conform to the defined type" - but `null` does not conform to the `string` type and there's also no `null` type in OpenAPI 2.0. [Nazar Gargol's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42797352/113116) is the only correct answer here.

Answer (score 2):

Just as a hint, because I stumpled upon this: When I added

```
type: string
nullable: true`
```

as described in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42797352/2750563 my service returned only `"fieldName": { "present": true }` instead of an actual value!

If you see this, simply add the `JsonNullableModule` to your Jackson serializer, for example, if using Spring:

```
@Component
public class JacksonConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    public void configureJackson(ObjectMapper mapper) {
        mapper.registerModule(new JsonNullableModule());
    }

}
```

Then everything looks fine again.