# How to add default argument values in C# client code from Swagger API definition

Tags: c#, swagger-editor

Has anyone had much experience converting Swagger API definitions to C#.NET client code?

Mostly, [Swagger Editor](https://editor.swagger.io) works ok, but the issue we have is that the generated code for some calls has a bunch of required-but-nullable arguments. Eg (truncated argument list for illustration only):

```
GetCustomers(bool? includeDeceased, string postalCode, string id, string dateAdded)
```

We would like the generated parameter list to be defined with default values to avoid having to explicitly provide null arguments. So something like this:

```
GetCustomers(bool? includeDeceased = null, string postalCode = null, int? id = null, string dateAdded = null)
```

This allows us to make the following call:

```
GetCustomers(postalCode: "12345")
```

Rather than:

```
GetCustomers(includeDeceased: null, postalCode="12345", id: null, dateAdded: null)
```

We've tried adding `"default": null` to the Swagger call definitions where appropriate but this doesn't result in the desired code (in fact, no change, so probably not supported).

Short of manually modifying the resulting client code – which we want to avoid so we can quickly and easily update our code to the latest API definitions – we're a bit stuck.

Comment: I'm assuming you own/develop the API and can change it. If so, have a look at this SO item on how you can create your yaml to say your parameter is nullable, with a default value (see comment to the answer).
 [Nullable Fields in Swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38139657/nullable-fields-in-swagger-on-node-js/38140597#38140597)

Comment: @FrankFajardo Nope, I don't. But I could request a correction to the Swagger definition or probably script changes to it if necessary. But the issue is actually the Swagger Editor `CsharpDotNet2` client code generator as far as I can tell, as the `csharp` one works as expected. Refer to my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems that the Swagger Editor **CsharpDotNet2** client code generator is the culprit here.

I just tried the bog-standard **csharp** client code generator and it added `= null` to all arguments not marked `"required": true`.

So I guess it's manually edit the CsharpDotNet2 generator or use the csharp one if you can.

**UPDATE** And, in case you're wondering, it turns out that the **csharp** generator is actually the newer one, targeted at .NET 4.5. I was thinking that if one had "DotNet" in the name and the other didn't that that was the one to go for. Silly me.